# Transparency in splash screen

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms, transparent, splash-screen

I saw the splash screen of the Corel-Draw 12 application and lost my mind!

What technique do they use? 
On application start-up they load a transparent image, use windows api or what?

How do they achieve this transparency?

Comment: Are you looking to do transparency in WPF or Win32 or WinForms or something else?

Comment: Actually it is about winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a demo project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/SplashScreen.aspx) for both VB.NET & C#.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, the image is drawn to a black rectangular background

Answer (score 0):

If you are using winforms with vb.net you can modify the opacity of any form by setting the `Form.Opacity` property.  I am not familiar with the splash screen you are speaking about but it shouldn't be too difficult to achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WPF, set the `AllowsTransparancy`, `WindowStyle` and `Background` attributes on the Window object:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  AllowsTransparency="True"
  WindowStyle="None"
  Background="Transparent">
  <!-- more -->
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also unfamiliar with this flash screen... but if it slowly fades or something, then I would go with Quintin's answer here.  Opacity at a certain percentage will show another form through yours.

If the splash screen is just an image and some of it is see-through and some of it isn't, then you can set the transparency key on your form to a certain color, then set the form's background color equal to that, and then whatever image you wish to display should be loaded into a picture box.  Make sure you use a .GIF image though! or some other format that supports deleting out the background. JPG's and BMP's are worthless here since their "empty" color becomes white instead of transparent.